# How to get an injected instance of a JSR-330 annotated external class

Tags: micronaut

Micronauts compile time dependency injection works great when I limit it to classes of my own local project.

But getting an instance injected of a class that resides in an external dependency (e.g handy-external-library.jar) however, fails...

The class of the external jar (e.g. "LdapConnector") does have a proper class level JSR-330 javax.inject.Singleton annotation set.

Note that I don't have control over the external jar, so I can't directly modify its source code or pom.xml

Seems to be a related issue: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1101

I tried to:

1. add the external dependency to the maven-compiler-plugin, thinking it would potentially make the handy-external-library.jar part of the annotation processors class path
2. fiddle around with the Introspected annotation thinking that it might implicitly register the annotation meta data

But whenever I use:

```
@Inject
private LdapConnector ldapConnector;
```

It results in:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [cool.api.HelloWorldController] could not be loaded: Failed to inject value for field [ldapConnector] of class: cool.api.HelloWorldController.
Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
```

Some details:

```
mn --version
| Micronaut Version: 1.1.2
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_171

mn create-app cool-api --build=maven --features=spock

mn
| Starting interactive mode...
| Enter a command name to run. Use TAB for completion:
mn> create-controller HelloWorld
mn> exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating beans for external classes is what the `@Factory` feature is for.

```
@Factory
class LdapFactory {

    @Singleton
    LdapConnector connector() {
        ... return an instance of LdapConnector
    }
}
```

See https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#factories

Comment: Thanks for your answer James,

The LdapConnector itself is relying on quite some other JRS-330 annotated classes (e.g. a client, configuration, etc).
The @Factory solution does add a bit to the code base and I am going to be responsible for correctly instantiating and wiring those beans myself. I was hoping Micronauts DI logic to take care of that.

We are using numerous libraries from other teams. Is there perhaps another solution I could look into? Like somehow adding external classes to an annotation processors' classpath?

Comment: @axiomaticbits I'm not sure if that is technically possible or not. Currently the classes that get generated to do the bean injection and instantiation are created in the same package as the original class. Creating bean definitions for classes in a jar would result in classes existing in the same package across jars. You can file an issue to ask for this to be looked into